# Convert/Merge [atlassian-localstack] tag to [localstack]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There is currently a [atlassian-localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-localstack) tag on Stack Overflow. As shown by visiting the  [original repo](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack), the localstack project is no longer under Atlassian. It's now its own project hosted at [localstack.cloud](https://localstack.cloud).

I just created a [localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstack) tag. I suggest keeping that tag and migrating [atlassian-localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-localstack) into it.

Comment: The tag is still sponsored by Atlassian.

Comment: Gotcha. That's unclear from the new page. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 9):

No, don't create a new tag.  The existing tag can be renamed if it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: Underderstood. Just cleared out the tag from my post. Not sure if that kills it or not.

Comment: It is indeed not maintained but still, there's some probability of the tag [atlassian-localstack] arising again. I suggest we make [atlassian-localstack] a synonym of [localstack]

Answer (score 0):

Since the [atlassian-localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-localstack) tag is no longer sponsored by Atlassian (which, as [Bhargav mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387106/convert-merge-atlassian-localstack-tag-to-localstack#comment711294_387106) was previously blocking this merge), I have pulled the trigger.

The [localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstack) tag is now the "master" tag, with [atlassian-localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-localstack) as a synonym, just to keep old bookmarks working properly.

I also updated the [localstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstack) tag wiki to point out the project's former name.